# Intermittent Entity framework 3.4 error in hosted environment (medium trust)

Tags: frameworks, entity

I have an application that is being hosted in medium trust environment (godaddy).  I am getting strange problem that occurs periodically when I am trying to use the application.

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

I have read a bunch of other posts that talk about issues running in a medium trust environment.  My question really goes to trying to understand why it works sometimes and other times I get the above message.  When error occurs it will eventually correct itself.  And obvously if I recycle IIS that fixes is as well.  I'm hoping their is a workaround for this.

Based on the callstack it looks like it related to esablishing the connection and trying to load the MetadataWorkspace from my assembly. My MetadataWorkspace is contained in my App_Code folder for my web app.

Partial Callstack:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.VerifyCodeBaseDiscovery(String codeBase)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName(Boolean copiedName)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DefaultAssemblyResolver.AssemblyComparer`1.Equals(T x, T y)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T value)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.Add(T item)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DefaultAssemblyResolver.GetAllDiscoverableAssemblies()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DefaultAssemblyResolver.GetWildcardAssemblies()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String    assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver   resolver)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.SplitPaths(String paths)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
```

I there a workaround for this?